# Tomcat without index.html show files in directory

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration, local

I was wondering how you could make tomcat show the files in a directory when an index.html is not in the root directory? Currently it gives me an error page.

```
description The requested resource 
(/Tutorials/ios/exercise-files/Ex_Files_iOS4_Web_Apps/Ch02/) is not available.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Tomcat's own `/conf/web.xml` file (or the one in *Servers* project if you're using Eclipse), find the `<servlet>` entry of the `DefaultServlet` and change the `listings` initialization parameter from `false` to `true`.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

#### See also:

- [Tomcat 7.0 documentation - the default servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html)